# Laplace's equation 2 variable PDE/chain rule show function is a solution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, chain-rule

The question is:
'Show that if f(x,y) is harmonic, then $f(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ is also harmonic using Laplace's equation: $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} = 0 $.

I end up with this using the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} = 2\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} + 4x^2\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u^2} + 8xy\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u \partial v} + 4y^2\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial v^2} $$

and

$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} = -2\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} + 4y^2\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u^2} + 4x^2\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial v^2} - 8xy\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u \partial v}$$

so: 
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} = (4x^2+4y^2)\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u^2} + (4x^2+4y^2)\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial v^2}$$

which is not equal to $0$ as far as I can tell. I thought you might be able to say $Fuu + Fvv = 0$ just because it's harmonic, but I think you are meant to be showing that **is harmonic**.

Any ideas or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I just edited your post. Thank you for using MathJax. Another time, though, please use the command \frac{a}{b} to write a fraction, e.g. derivatives. Thank you. More tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. Sorry I'm new to MathJax. I will use it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** equal to zero as

$$ \begin{split}
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} &= (4x^2+4y^2)\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u^2} + (4x^2+4y^2)\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial v^2}\\
&= (4x^2+4y^2)\left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial v^2} \right) \\
&=0
\end{split}$$

as $f(u, v)$ is harmonic.

Comment: Yer ok that's what I thought. Thanks for that.